# Oracle 19c Installation Error: [INS-08802] Unable to instantiate the View class referred by View ID 'QuickInstallUI'

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle19c

I'm trying to install this Oracle version(https://www.oracle.com/tr/database/technologies/oracle19c-windows-downloads.html) on Win10. I didn't install any Oracle product to this computer before. I tried some directory changings and and it doesn't work, couldn't reach any helpful suggestion further for this issue. Apologize for my bad explanation, I'm not naitive English speaker. I hope I can get some solution.  Thanks for interesting.

Here is the installer's respond:

> **[INS-08802]** *Unable to instantiate the View class referred by View ID*
> *'QuickInstallUI'.*

> Cause - The given class do not represent a valid View class or an
> unexpected error occured while instantiating it.  Action - No
> additional information available.  Summary
>  - java.lang.NullPointerException

And also these are from log file:

```
INFO:  [Mar 4, 2021 1:17:53 AM] Get view named [QuickInstallUI]
WARNING:  [Mar 4, 2021 1:17:53 AM] Failed to load the view [QuickInstallUI] . Reason: .
Refer associated stacktrace #oracle.install.commons.flow.ViewManager:1832
INFO:  [Mar 4, 2021 1:17:53 AM] Terminating all background operations
INFO:  [Mar 4, 2021 1:17:53 AM] Terminated all background operations
SEVERE:  [Mar 4, 2021 1:17:53 AM] [FATAL] [INS-08802] Unable to instantiate the View class referred by View ID 'QuickInstallUI'.
   CAUSE: The given class do not represent a valid View class or an unexpected error occured while instantiating it.
   ACTION: No additional information available.
   SUMMARY:
       - java.lang.NullPointerException.
Refer associated stacktrace #oracle.install.commons.util.exception.AbstractErrorAdvisor:1840
```

Comment: How far did the installer get? Perhaps try a software-only installation option

Comment: It's working until create user part. I'm choosing "Create New Windows User" and as soon as I click next button, this error shows up.
I tried software-only option and unfortunately same thing happened.

Comment: Is this is work PC ? Some times those things are locked down at a domain level. Perhaps try the "Use system acct" option

Comment: Hey there... Got the same issue on Windows 10 (Family). Have installed the same release on a Windows 10 Pro without problem. If someone have found a way out, please let us know...

Comment: @Overdoseflow I was able to install it by copying all the setup files into `C:\db_home` and executing the installer (`setup.exe`, _not_ `setup.bat`) from there.